# .slideToggle() check

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I got an menu with different slidetoggles in it. the javascript looks like this:

```
$('.toggler').live('click',function(){
              $(this).parent().children().toggle();  //swaps the display:none between the two spans
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle();  //swap the display of the main content with slide action
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content2').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.div2').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.ap2').css('display', 'block');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content3').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.div3').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.ap3').css('display', 'block');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content4').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.div4').css('display', 'none');
              $(this).parent().parent().find('.ap4').css('display', 'block');

          });
```

Now u can see that once i click an .toggler he sets certain area's to display:none and some to display:block. But what would be more perfect if i can replace this part of code:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content2').css('display', 'none');
```

To some code that checks if the block is open and so yes then it slides to close it. I don't know if this is possible but it would look nicer if it does.

Thanks in forwards!

Here is the HTML:

```
                        <div id="spacerouter"><div id="spacer"><div id="spacerin"></div><div id="spacerinr"></div></div></div>
                <div class='toggleHolder'>
                    <div id="company" class='toggler ap1'>
                        <div id="companysiton"></div>
                            <div id="companyname">
                                <h1>Siton Suzenaar</h1>
                                <h2>Hyundai / Opel / Chevrolet</h2>
                            </div><!-- companyname -->
                    </div><!-- company -->
                    <div id="company2" class='toggler div1' style='display:none;'>
                        <div id="companysiton"></div>
                            <div id="companyname">

                                <h2>Hyundai / Opel / Chevrolet</h2>
                            </div><!-- companyname -->
                    </div><!-- company -->
                </div><!-- toggleHolder -->
                <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;' id="toggled_content">
                    <h3>



                    </h3>
                    <h3>
                    <a href="mailto:mail@mailhost.nl">mail@mailhost.nl</a><br />

                    </h3>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the visible & hidden selectors and add a common class to all your elements that need to be toggled.

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.commonClass:visible').css('display', 'none');

$(this).parent().parent().find('.commonClass:hidden').css('display', 'block');
```

Or better yet

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.commonClass').slideToggle()
```

Comment: But if i use $(this).parent().parent().find('.commonClass').slideToggle()
 then it would slide the content open when its closed? But i need an script that checks if its open or closed. And when its open then close only that div.

Comment: @Augus Sorry, I am not sure I understand. Do you mean you want to check if the clicked div with the toggler class is open and if so, close it? If that is the case you'd call $(this).slideToggle(); your function here $('.toggler').live('click',function(){}). But I have a feeling that I might still be misunderstanding.

Comment: I want to check if an other div is open, and if so close this div with an slide. So when i click on the div with .toggler check if .toggle_content is open and if it is then slide the .toggle_content to close.

Comment: @Augus The call $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle(); in your function is correct. Though it sounds like you have multiple elements with the toggle_content class and if that is the case then you will have to enclose the .toggle_holder & toggle_content within another div for you to get the correct one like this <div><div class="toggle_holder"></div><div class="toggle_content"></div></div> <div><div class="toggle_holder"></div><div class="toggle_content"></div></div>

Comment: Well every slider for an other class. So i got .toggle_content , .toggle_content2, etc. So that wouldn't be the problem. And ur call is also ok. except I want to check if the div with the class is closed before i slide toggle it. Else if its already closed it would open.

Comment: @Augus to check if a div is already closed use the ':hidden' selector in conjunction with he class to retrieve only hidden items or possibly use the 'is' method http://api.jquery.com/is/ with the ':hidden' selector. $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').is(":hidden").

Comment: there we come a litle closer. Thanks alot, but the .toggled_content has an style='display:none;' when its not open. But has no style when it is open. So what statement can i use in .is() to check if its open.

Comment: @Augus you can use ':visible' to check for visibility instead http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/. .is(":visible")

Comment: @Augus Did I finally get what you were asking? lol Sometimes it's difficult to give the best advice without seeing the complete picture.

Comment: Im going to try it later today, ill update when i got some results.